# How to make a row in a html table clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have this Javascript function which creates a table in html. Which does exactly what I want.

```
var thead = '<table><thead><tr><td>#</td><td>Name</td><td>Id</td></tr></thead><tbody>\n';
for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++)
{
    tbody += '<tr class="row">';
    tbody += '<td>' + (i+1) + '</td>';
    tbody += '<td>' + dataArray[i].Device_Name + '</td>';
    tbody += '<td>' + dataArray[i].Device_Id + '</td>';         
    tbody += '</tr>\n';     
}
var tfooter = '</tbody></table>';
document.getElementById('dataTableDiv').innerHTML = thead + tbody + tfooter;
```

Now I want to run some code everytime I click on a certain row. For now it doesn't matter which row is click as long as the code is being executed. Here is the code that should handle the row click. All the other click actions work perfectly inside the `$(document).ready(function(){});` But for some reason, the click handler for the table doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".row").click(function() 
    {
        console.log("Blablabla")
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you create your table in a script after document loading, click handler can't be attached to tr click event because they don't exists at the moment document.ready event is triggered. You can try to put your table construction into a function, an call this function before your rows click handler definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are generating HTML dynamically from Jquery so try **event delegation** as shown below :-

```
$(document).on('click','.row',function(){
    // Your Code...
});
```

OR

```
$(document.body).on('click','.row',function(){
    // Your Code...
});
```

OR(adding **Jai's** useful comment in answer)

```
$('#dataTableDiv').on('click','.row',function(){
    // Your Code...
});
```

Comment: I was just about to answer that. :D

Comment: Will work, but pretty heavy. He does not need it if he only create the table at document loading and not adding rows afterwards.

Comment: Worked. Thank you very much sir. Been trying to figure this out for 2 days :-(

Comment: better one is `$('#dataTableDiv').on(event, selector, fn);`